# Batch-Register Open-Generic Types with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am using Simple Injector because it is really easy to assign a bunch of generic interfaces to their concretions. I have run into a roadblock though when my generics are two levels deep. I was hoping that there is a simple solution to this I haven't thought of. Here is an example of manually hooking up a single dependency:

```cs
container
    .Register<ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<Schools>>, UpdateCommandHandler<Schools>>();
```

This is what I would like to do instead:

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<>>), modelAssembly);
```

but that does not compile.

Comment: Is it maybe an option to create an intermediate interface `IUpdateCommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler<UpdateCommand<T>>` have your `UpdateCommandHandler<T>` inherit that and register that?

Comment: @Knoop, that's just over-complicating things :-) Having such an extra interface complicates your code tremendously, because decorators can't easily be applied to that new interface (as they will be written for `ICommandHandler<T>`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Register` Auto-Registration API *skips* open-generic implementations, such as `UpdateCommandHandler<T>`, because these types typically need special handling. Instead, `Register` will only select non-generic implementations.

To register this open-generic implementation, you will have to register it explicitly:

```cs
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(UpdateCommandHandler<>));
```

Alternatively, in case you have many open-generic implementations that can be registered in any particular order, you can Auto-Register all non-generic and open-generic implementations (excluding decorators) as follows:

```cs
var handlerTypes =
    container.GetTypesToRegister(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] { modelAssembly },
        new TypesToRegisterOptions { IncludeGenericTypeDefinitions = true });

container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), handlerTypes);
```

Comment: The registration you show in your question solely works for that specific closed-generic type, while the registration I show in my answer works all closed-generic versions of that implementation. It can be considered a form of batch-registration.

Comment: I advise against defining a new IUpdateCommandHandler, because that makes it impossible to reuse decorators.

Comment: Sorry when I posted my latest comment that page wasn't up to date. This answer is correct Thanks! I wish SO had some kind of DM, last night in thinking about this problem it started casting doubts on the merits of CQRS. Because once this is implemented it looks to me like I have just made the most complicated wrapping of the repository pattern in history.